# Is there a way to speedup gropuby.apply()?

Tags: python, pandas-groupby

I am trying to execute groupby line of code. But the execution time is very slow I am trying to find the most frequent ID for a particular item_qty and its frequency

I am trying to get the most frequently used ID for a particular item_code_qty and its frequency

My code is as follows :

```
# Getting the most frequently used ID for that item_code_qty and its frequency

data_gr = (
    data.groupby(["item_code_qty"])["ID"]
    .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
    .reset_index()
)

data_count = data_gr.rename(
    {"ID": "Frequency", "level_1": "ID"}, axis=1
)
```

Output looks like this:

```
   item_cd_qty              ID      Frequency
0   825 x 1                 40        2
1   625 x 1                 44        2
2   492 x 1                 40      130
3   492 x 2                 40        2
4   136 x 1                 42        6
```

Is there a better way of handling this? I would appreciate your feedback. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `pandarallel`:

```
from pandarallel import pandarallel
pandarallel.initialize()

data_gr =
    data.groupby(["item_code_qty"])["ID"]
    .parallel_apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
    .reset_index()
```

Or you can use `multiprocessing`, there are many answers about it on this site.

Comment: Thanks. I am getting AttributeError: 'SeriesGroupBy' object has no attribute 'parallel_apply'

Comment: Then you have to somehow convert `Series` to `DataFrame`, `pandarallel` doesn't work with `Series`.